# php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64 when installing phpmyadmin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I have successfully installed php70 and mysql. But when i am trying to install phpmyadmin by

```
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
```

And Then

```
$ sudo yum install -y phpMyAdmin
```

It gives me

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Also after google sometimes i found a solution that try this

```
sudo yum install php70-mbstring
```

And i have tried this also, Still facing same error.

Any suggestion...?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess that you are following the Amazon tutorial to install phpMyAdmin ?

I had the same problem today and resolved it by uninstall PHP 7.0 with the yum command (the same given by Amazon with 'remove' instead of 'install' :

```
sudo yum remove httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
```

and installed PHP 5.6 instead :

```
sudo yum install httpd24 php56 mysql56-server php56-mysqlnd
```

I don't know if this is a good solution, but it worked and I could install phpMyAdmin without dependencies problem. I hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks @Eric.....This solved my issue.
I think there is problem with php7 version. ??

Comment: You only need to remove and reinstall the needed php56 packages like so: `sudo yum remove php70 php70-mysqlnd` and `sudo yum install php56 php56-mysqlnd`. No need to remove packages you will directly reinstall again.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea since php7 has a lot of improvements compared to php5

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I have php56 installed and I get this error.
`Error: php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64`

Comment: I just needed to install php56 before phpmyadmin. I didn't have httpd24 php7 installed previously : `sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install php56`

Comment: @Muhammad Hannan You also need to remove php-common before following the instructions above using `sudo yum remove php-common` and then proceed with installation. Updated guide for Amazon Linux AMI from amazon itself is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)

Comment: I Just tried this command `php56-mysqlnd` and restarted my server using `sudo service httpd restart` and walla

Answer (score 12):

In case you want to keep php7, I found a solution with AWS Amazon experts. 
Just use : 
sudo yum install -y php70-mbstring

Comment: how should I do it? 
i kept 7.0 and installed sudo yum install -y php70-mbstring
still the error is the same.. :(

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue today.  I had some success downloading phpmyadmin from phpmyadmin.net, and following their instructions. I did run into a different problem during the setup of phpmyadmin....

So, I punted on resolving this with the Amazon AMI for now, and chose to install the Bitnami LAMP AMI to get me going quicker.  It comes with phpmyadmin configured.

NOTE: Bitnami's AMI is running PHP Version 5.6.29, so I would say it's valid to follow the previous post's advice and downgrade, unless your web application specifically needs PHP 7.0.