# Install php-fpm in in linux(Amazon ami) no package avaliable error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install `php-fpm` on my ec2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09).

`sudo yum install php-fpm` returns  conflict errors.

> Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

so i tried to list the available packages

`sudo yum search fpm` it returns

```
php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php54-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php55-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php56-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php70-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
```

Now i try to install with `php70-fpm.x86_64` it returns no package avaliable error.

php version :7.0.14

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php56-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86\_64 when installing phpmyadmin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526831/php56-common-conflicts-with-php-common-5-3-29-1-8-amzn1-x86-64-when-installing-p)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue with this command

`sudo yum install php70-fpm`