# ec2 amazon, can't read /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf: No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I'm running ec2 Instance on amazon, I followed the exact command line as mentioned on official Amazon Doc when I tape `sudo sed -i -e 's/127.0.0.1/your_ip_address/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf` it gives me this error `can't read /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf: No such file or directory` 
and I can't connect to phpmyadmin
I put my own id address of course.
When I tape  `sudo yum list installed httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd`
I can see that `mysql56-server.x86_64` is installed.
It's the second instance that I have create and  gives ma the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed phpMyAdmin?

```
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum install -y phpMyAdmin
```

Assuming you are using this guide - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

What is the output of

```
sudo ls -lh /etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

Comment: Yes I followed the amazon doc, the output of `sudo ls -lh /etc/httpd/conf.d/`  is 
`total 24K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.9K Jan 19 16:56 autoindex.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  347 Jan 19 16:54 notrace.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 May 19 08:38 php.conf -> /etc/alternatives/php.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.3K Mar  6 19:49 php-conf.7.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  366 Jan 19 16:56 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.3K Jan 19 16:54 userdir.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  500 Jan 19 16:54 welcome.conf`

Comment: What about the output of sudo yum info phpMyAdmin

Comment: Sorry I didn't response to you quickly here's the output of `sudo yum info phpMyAdmin`

Comment: `....
Available Packages
Name        : phpMyAdmin
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 4.0.10.19
Release     : 1.el6
Size        : 4.2 M
Repo        : epel/x86_64
Summary     : Handle the administration of MySQL over the World Wide Web
URL         : https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
License     : GPLv2+
Description : phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP intended to handle the
...`

Comment: That means that phpMyAdmin isn't installed. You should see Installled packages and Repo: installed From repo: epel/x86_64 rather than available packages with Repo: epel/x86_64. Run the following

Comment: sudo yum install phpMyAdmin

Comment: It's working now, I find the solution here I remove php 7 package and install php56 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526831/php56-common-conflicts-with-php-common-5-3-29-1-8-amzn1-x86-64-when-installing-p